# How to typeset contradiction symbol?

Tags: math-mode

By contradiction symbol I mean this

[image]

This is what I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\Rightarrow\Leftarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

But there is some space between the head of two arrows.

Comment: Whatever you do, define a command `\contradiction` that outputs what you want. That way not only you can easily change the definition in case you want to tweak it a bit, but also your code will be much more clean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might add a negativ space `\!` which results in no space between the two symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

As @Rethliopuks noted in the comments, the package `tipa` disables the usage of `\!` in mathmode as negative space. If you use this package (or any other package which disables `\!`) you might use

```
\Rightarrow\mskip-\thinmuskip\Leftarrow
```

instead for the same results (`\mskip-\thinmuskip` is the default definition of `\!`).

Comment: Seems like I was too slow :(

Comment: But at least you explained what the `\!` is for.

Comment: @TeXnician That' why I voted for Skillmon's answer, hahaha!

Comment: @CarLaTeX The problem if someone always tries to be fast ;) But I also voted for Skillmon's answer.

Comment: @TeXnician "Presto e bene non vanno insieme" = "Quick and well don't go together" (Italian proverb). :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX You could have left out the translation (my Latin/Italian language knowledge mix would have been good enough). But you're absolutely right.

Comment: @TeXnician Oooh, you're polyglot, then! However, the translation is for the others...

Comment: A very interesting conflict: the package `tipa` disables the function of `\!`, so, for a quick solution, consider disabling the package to use this functionality. Or if you would like to prove contradiction in some hardcore linguistics paper -- then you might want to define the conflict away somehow.

Comment: @Rethliopuks if you use the package `tipa` the following gives good results (works without `tipa`, too): `\Rightarrow\kern-0.5ex\Leftarrow`

Comment: The “explicit form” of `\!` is `\mskip-\thinmuskip`

Comment: @egreg yeah, I could have looked that up... Thanks anyway, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

That gives what you want (added `\!`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Math symbols usually have sidebearings and, at least with Computer Modern fonts. The sidebearings turn out to be 1mu, in the case of `\Leftarrow` and `\Rightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt} % just for the example

\fbox{$\Rightarrow$} \fbox{$\Leftarrow$}
$\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

\fbox{$\Rightarrow\mspace{-1mu}$} \fbox{$\mspace{-1mu}\Leftarrow$}
$\Rightarrow\mspace{-2mu}\Leftarrow$

\fbox{$\Rightarrow\mspace{-1.5mu}$} \fbox{$\mspace{-1.5mu}\Leftarrow$}
$\Rightarrow\mspace{-3mu}\Leftarrow$

\fbox{$\Rightarrow\mspace{-2mu}$} \fbox{$\mspace{-2mu}\Leftarrow$}
$\Rightarrow\mspace{-4mu}\Leftarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Judging from the above pictures, I guess you want

```
\newcommand{\contradiction}{%
  \ensuremath{{\Rightarrow\mspace{-2mu}\Leftarrow}}%
}
```

Yes, with `\ensuremath`, because `\contradiction` could be used both in displays (during a proof) or in text.

Using a macro is better because it can be tailored based on the actual fonts used. For instance, if `fourier` is used, the pictures are

[image]

so probably `\mspace{-3mu}` should be used for this case.